# For a native android application that seg faults, why is there no stack trace in logcat?

Tags: android, logcat

Pretty self explanatory.  I compiled a native c++ exe using the ndk.  When I run the app, it gets a SIGSEGV, seg faults and exits.  There is no stack trace or cpu context in the logcat.

Why?  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

there are two tools you can use to debug your `sigsev`. `ndk-stac`k and `arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line` located into your `$NDK` dir.The first help you to filter the stacktrace and addr2line translates program addresses into file names and line num. Check into your `$NDK` dir, for the documentation.

Comment: The stack trace is not available in logcat, so both this utilities do no good.  I read over ndk-stack.  This depends on the stack trace being available in the logcat, starting with the line *** *** *** ***.  again, addr2line depends on the stack trace being there.

Comment: The stacktrace for native errors doesn't fit any application filter, you have to look for it in the All messages (no filters) tab OR adding a filter for the tag DEBUG

Comment: Old post, but for anyone Googling - you can find the full error log in your `\data\tombstones` directory on your device.

Answer (score -2):

You may need to enable logging to logcat for STDIO and STDERR.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd