# Does this SIGSEGV error message mean the problem is occuring in an asynctask

Tags: android, segmentation-fault

For some devices getting an error in my android app:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 31044 (AsyncTask #5)
```

I've got C++ code in the app, so I initially thought it had to do with that, but I'm not using any asynctasks, and the C++ code is always run in a thread. That's why I'm  interested to know if the error must be happening in asynctask and not a thread, because that means the problem is not with my C++ code.

Comment: Basically, yes. If a thread is named "AsyncTask X", it's probably because it was started by an AsyncTask. You should upload more of the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. But it's a segfault, there is no stacktrace.

Comment: FYI segfaults do generally have stacktraces, if it's missing that suggests stack corruption as well. Also, recommend checking out the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708415/6759241).